# How to print a footer that works on multiple pages without overlapping page content?

Tags: .net

```
thead { display: table-header-group; } - It's working in Chrome
tfoot { display: table-footer-group; } - It's not working in Chrome
```

How to solve this problem in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a master page having both Header as well as the footer and make use of what need to be Visible in some pages and what not in others.

You need to use the below code for inclusion of master page.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Example.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage_Example" %>.
```

Hope this answers your question.